# When and where to use $eval and $parse

Tags: angularjs

When and where to use $eval and $parse in angularjs.

```
eReaderBook.controller("mainCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.test = "asdasd";
    var s = "{{test}}";
    console.log($scope.$eval("s"))
})
```

why console.log returns undefined.

Comment: What do expect to see in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined for the following reason.

$eval method works on scope variable. Here your variable `s` is just a normal javascript variable. But if you try to log `'test'` as follows. You will see the proper value is being printed.

```
console.log($scope.$eval("test"))
```

If you try without quote as follows

```
$scope.$eval(s)
```

Then you will find

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key

because value of s is {{test}}. So then eval will try to find the value from the scope as $scope.{{test}} which is invalid and has syntax error.

More over `$scope.$eval('a+b')` means `$scope.a+$scope.b`

So in easy words those expression which you can write inside binding block `{{ expression }}` of angular, you can also write inside $**eval** method as string.

```
{{WHAT EVER YOU CAN WRITE HERE}}
$scope.$eval('YOU CAN WRITE HERE ALSO');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eReaderBook.controller("mainCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.test = "asdasd";
    var s = "test";
    console.log($scope.$eval(s))
})
```

`$scope.$eval`, unlike `eval()` already expects AngularJS's recognized format.
Also don't need the `"` in eval

Answer (score 0):

$parse is an Angular service which converts an expression into a function. The function can then be invoked and passed a context (usually scope) in order to retrieve the expression's value.

$eval is a scope method which executes an expression on the current scope and returns the result.

For more information refer:

http://ng.malsup.com/#!/$parse-and-$eval

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse